# apt-get not getting latest version on some servers

Tags: ubuntu, apt

I've got Percona DB 5.6 on several Ubuntu 12.04 servers.  On a few of them, I've been able to successfully upgrade to the latest version (5.6.17) using

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
```

On several others, apt-get update + upgrade tells me there's nothing to do, although the version installed there is only 5.6.15.  Why isn't it finding the most recent version?

Up-to-date version from servers that did update: "Server version: 5.6.17-65.0-587.precise-log (Ubuntu)"

Version from servers that are not updating: "Server version: 5.6.15-63.0-log Percona Server (GPL), Release 63.0"

I have confirmed that the following lines are in /etc/apt/sources.list on all servers:

```
deb http://repo.percona.com/apt precise main
deb-src http://repo.percona.com/apt precise main
```

(and it had to work at some point, because they were all installed originally using apt-get)

EDIT: From estibordo's suggestion, I'm adding in the output of

```
apt-cache policy percona-server-server-5.6
```

(percona-server-common-5.6 & percona-server-client-5.6 are identical to this too)

From the servers that are not upgrading:

```
percona-server-server-5.6:
  Installed: 1:5.6.15-rel63.0-519.precise
  Candidate: 1:5.6.15-rel63.0-519.precise
  Version table:
 *** 1:5.6.15-rel63.0-519.precise 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.6.17-65.0-587.precise 0
        500 http://repo.percona.com/apt/ precise/main amd64 Packages
```

On my servers that did upgrade, this is the output:

```
percona-server-server-5.6:
  Installed: 5.6.17-65.0-587.precise
  Candidate: 5.6.17-65.0-587.precise
  Version table:
 *** 5.6.17-65.0-587.precise 0
        500 http://repo.percona.com/apt/ precise/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Why the difference, or more importantly, how do I fix the ones that are stuck on 5.6.15?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that

```
apt-cache policy percona-server-server
```

is what you need. It will provide the information about the installed version and if there are other candidates to install. It will also tell you from which repositories the packages came from.

You might use the same command with a wildcard, like:

```
apt-cache policy percona*
```

Comment: I've edited the question to include the output of apt-cache policy, since it's a little big for a comment.  Thanks for the suggestion - at least I see where there is a difference now (except I don't know why or what it means).

Comment: To fix the problem, you can install the specific package version you want by doing:
`sudo apt-get install percona-server-server-5.6=5.6.17-65.0-587.precise`
I really don't know how this happened to you, but in the package number (on servers not upgrading) there is an additional epoch number **1:** before the package number. Instead of just `5.6.15-rel63.0-519.precise` you have `1:5.6.15-rel63.0-519.precise`
Maybe this is causing problems.

Comment: Yes, that works.  Although it oddly warns me that I'm performing a downgrade before asking to continue.  But now the cache policy does look the same as the other servers, so hopefully it will continue to work in the future.  For completeness, and anyone else reading this as related specifically to percona, I also had to install percona-server-client-5.6 and percona-server-common-5.6 with the same =5.6.17-65.0-587.precise version.

Answer (score 2):

Having the same problem currently with some Ubuntu PPAs: Look closely at the version number of the installed package. It has a leading 1: at the beginning (the "epoch" - see https://askubuntu.com/questions/441879/why-do-some-packages-have-extra-numbers-on-the-front-of-their-version-string), which leads Apt to think that it's a higher version than the actual higher version from the repo. Did the old installation come from a PPA, or did they perchance change the version numbers?

Anyway, since the output does not state where the currently installed package comes from, the repository might have been removed from your configuration in the meantime.

I think it would be best to remove (not purge; removing should leave all your configuration intact; nonetheless, be sure to backup the corresponding folder in /etc) the current package, then (just to be safe) do an `apt-get update && apt-get clean` again, then install the package again normally with `apt-get install`. It should then have forgotten about the version with the 1: prefix and install the most recent from the repository.